# Why rancher service disconnected sometimes?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, docker, containers, rancher

I used Rancher to deploy a Rails application.

I created two services. One used for install node packages and db migration. The other one used for Rails application.

The second service works well. But the first one sometimes disconnected. So it is necessary to install the node packages again. It's crazy!

The services are:

- a. myapp_setup service: sometimes disconnected
- b. myapp service: works well
- c. postgres service: works well

a depends on c. b depends on a and c.

---

## Addition

For example, I created a service to setup the main application. When running it to install something like database migration and node.js npm packages. From the log I know, it sometimes disconnected. And when restart again, it will reinstall the packages again. So the main project in container b can't works well.

[image]

Answer (score -1):

`disconnected` is not one of the possible states for a Service so I'm not sure what you mean.  Are you talking about the Host(s) the Service is running on?  Hosts have a `disconnected` state, which means the agent container on it does not have an active connection to the `rancher/server` container.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I have edited the question and added the log picture.